# How to pull listed data from several web pages - Cannot locate table tag

Tags: excel, vb.net, web, web-scraping, html

First of all I have read ALOT of different answers online in relation to this topic but I have to admit I am really struggling to adapt them to what I need so please any help is very much appreciated!

I need to extract the data listed on the following webpage (Pages 1-7) i.e. Fund Name, Price, Currency etc https://toolkit.financialexpress.net/santanderam and pull this data through to excel.

I have the below code that will open the IE page (which is working):

```
' return the document containg the DOM of the page strWebAddress
' returns Nothing if the timeout lngTimeoutInSeconds was reached
Public Function GetIEDocument(ByVal strWebAddress As String, Optional ByVal lngTimeoutInSeconds As Long = 15) As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim IE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim IEDocument As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim dateNow As Date

' create an IE application, representing a tab
Set IE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

' optionally make the application visible, though it will work perfectly fine in the background otherwise
IE.Visible = True

' open a webpage in the tab represented by IE and wait until the main request successfully finished
' times out after lngTimeoutInSeconds with a warning
IE.Navigate strWebAddress
dateNow = Now
Do While IE.Busy
    If Now > DateAdd("s", lngTimeoutInSeconds, dateNow) Then Exit Function
Loop

' retrieve the webpage's content (that is, the HTML DOM) and wait until everything is loaded (images, etc.)
' times out after lngTimeoutInSeconds with a warning
Set IEDocument = IE.Document
dateNow = Now
Do While IEDocument.ReadyState <> "complete"
    If Now > DateAdd("s", lngTimeoutInSeconds, dateNow) Then Exit Function
Loop

Set GetIEDocument = IEDocument
End Function
```

However I cannot find the table tag that contains all other tags that I am interested to allow the rest of the code to pull through the data, The below code is what I have so far:

```
Public Sub GetTeamData()
Dim strWebAddress As String
Dim strH2AnchorContent As String
Dim IEDocument As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim objH2 As MSHTML.HTMLHeaderElement
Dim objTable As MSHTML.HTMLTable
Dim objRow As MSHTML.HTMLTableRow
Dim objCell As MSHTML.HTMLTableCell
Dim lngRow As Long
Dim lngColumn As Long

' initialize some variables that should probably better be passed as paramaters or defined as constants
strWebAddress = "https://toolkit.financialexpress.net/santanderam"
strH2AnchorContent = "   "

' open page
Set IEDocument = GetIEDocument(strWebAddress)
If IEDocument Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Timeout reached opening this address:" & vbNewLine & strWebAddress, vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If

' retrieve anchor element
For Each objH2 In IEDocument.getElementsByTagName("h2")
   If objH2.innerText = strH2AnchorContent Then Exit For
Next objH2
If objH2 Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Could not find """ & strH2AnchorContent & """ in DOM!", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If

' traverse HTML tree to desired table element
' * move up one element in the hierarchy
' * skip two elements to proceed to the third (interjected each time with whitespace that is interpreted as an element of its own)
' * move down two elements n the hierarchy
Set objTable = objH2.parentElement _
                    .NextSibling.NextSibling _
                    .NextSibling.NextSibling _
                    .NextSibling.NextSibling _
                    .Children(0) _
                   .Children(0)

 '   iterate over the table and output its contents
lngRow = 1
 For Each objRow In objTable.Rows
    lngColumn = 1
     For Each objCell In objRow.Cells
         Cells(lngRow, lngColumn) = objCell.innerText
        lngColumn = lngColumn + 1
     Next objCell
     lngRow = lngRow + 1
 Next
End Sub
```

I am assuming if I can locate the correct table tag to enter in the line below:

```
 strH2AnchorContent = "  "
```

Then the above will work? If so can anyone help with finding the correct tag or advise where I am going wrong with the above?

Again any help would be REALLY appreciated!

Thanks

**Edit 1**

Updated code:

```
    ' open a webpage in the tab represented by IE and wait until the main request successfully finished
' times out after lngTimeoutInSeconds with a warning
IE.Navigate strWebAddress
dateNow = Now
Do While IE.Busy
    If Now > DateAdd("s", lngTimeoutInSeconds, dateNow) Then Exit Function
Loop

' retrieve the webpage's content (that is, the HTML DOM) and wait until everything is loaded (images, etc.)
' times out after lngTimeoutInSeconds with a warning
Set IEDocument = IE.Document
dateNow = Now
Do While IEDocument.ReadyState <> "complete"
    If Now > DateAdd("s", lngTimeoutInSeconds, dateNow) Then Exit Function
Loop

Set GetIEDocument = IEDocument
End Function

Public Sub GetTeamData()
Dim strWebAddress As String
Dim strH2AnchorContent As String
Dim IEDocument As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim objH2 As MSHTML.HTMLHeaderElement
Dim obTable As MSHTML.HTMLTable
Dim objRow As MSHTML.HTMLTableRow
Dim objCell As MSHTML.HTMLTableCell
Dim lngRow As Long
Dim lngColumn As Long

' initialize some variables that should probably better be passed as paramaters or defined as constants
strWebAddress = "https://toolkit.financialexpress.net/santanderam"


' open page
Set IEDocument = GetIEDocument(strWebAddress)
If IEDocument Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Timeout reached opening this address:" & vbNewLine &     strWebAddress, vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If

' retrieve anchor element
Set oTable = IEDocument.getElementById("Price_1_1")
Debug.Print oTable.innerText

' iterate over the table and output its contents
lngRow = 1
For Each objRow In oTable.Rows
    lngColumn = 1
    For Each objCell In objRow.Cells
        Cells(lngRow, lngColumn) = objCell.innerText
        lngColumn = lngColumn + 1
    Next objCell
    lngRow = lngRow + 1
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Examing this line, `If objH2.innerText = strH2AnchorContent`. What is `strH2AnchorContent`? If it is a search criterion it is more likely to be somewhere in the `innerText` than to represent the entire `innerText` as your code demands.

Comment: @Variatus after reading up on issues similar to mine, I understand structurally important tags have an id attribute that is unique. In the example I based the above on this was the variable that was attributed to the table heading i.e  strH2AnchorContent = "Tournament brackets" where the webpage code had the following lines <div class="wrapper"><h2 class="tournament-heading">Tournament brackets</h2></div However I am struggling to adapt this to the webpage I require the data from.

Comment: I don't think you need to get the header and then siblings. Table seem to have an `id`. I would use `GetElementById` and get the table by its 'ID'

Comment: @Zac Thank you very much ... admittedly I'm not hugely familiar with this but will I try and change the above code, would you be able to advise on a starting point ?? It would be really appreciated!

Comment: Start with the line I pointed out above. `Debug.Print objH2.innerText` prints the inner text to your Immediate window. Once you see what you found you can decide if it is what you want.

Comment: @Variatus thank you for your help it is really appreciated... but I will completely admit this is definitely above my current level of understanding/skill set unfortunately

Comment: I'm trying not to re-write the code for you :) but where you have `For Each objH2 In IEDocument.getElementsByTagName("h2")`, comment out the loop and replace it with something like: `Set oTable = IEDocument.GetElementByID("Price_1_1")`. That should give you the table. Now you can perform your next task. Also, I wouldn't undersell yourself, from what I can see, you are fully capable of understanding this task. Good luck

Comment: @Zac Thanks :) - ah I am trying can only get headings for Chart/Factsheet with no data any ideas what im doing wrong?  
    `Set oTable = IEDocument.getElementById("Price_1_1")
    Debug.Print oTable.innerText
    
        lngRow = 1
    For Each objRow In oTable.Rows
        lngColumn = 1
        For Each objCell In objRow.Cells
            Cells(lngRow, lngColumn) = objCell.innerText
            lngColumn = lngColumn + 1
        Next objCell
        lngRow = lngRow + 1
    Next
End Sub`

Comment: Have to log off now but I'll check this again tomorrow. If you haven't resolved it, I'll have a go at it. Can you update the code in your description to how you have it now? It will make it easier

Comment: @Zac Ah still no luck :( ... I have added the updated code under Edit 1 above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working fine, problem is that you are trying to capture data from the table before it is loaded. I added a simple **`Wait`** loop for 5 seconds and you current code captured the data. Below is the loop I added just before **`Set oTable = IEDocument.getElementById("Price_1_1")`** statement:

```
dateNow = Now
bExitLoop = False
lngTimeoutInSeconds = 5
Do While Not bExitLoop
    If Now > DateAdd("s", lngTimeoutInSeconds, dateNow) Then Exit Do
Loop
```

Code above is a static 5 second wait. You could make it more dynamic.. I'll leave that there as a brain teaser :)

Comment: Ive got it working now! Thank you! ... one more question though I can get the data to pull through from the first page but I'm not sure how to pull the data from the next pages (1-7) any ideas?

Comment: I cant provide more than one answer for the same query so: look into **`GetElementByClassName`** or **`QuerySelector`**. That will enable you to get the 'Next' button as it seems to have a class name. You can then click on it while it exists

Comment: Ah ok I have tried the following (I posted a second query with my code) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45356779/code-not-pulling-data-after-first-webpage-into-excel but not having any luck at getting the data im not sure where im going wrong :(