# Code not pulling data after first webpage into excel

Tags: excel, web-scraping, vba

I have the below code that will pull through data from a table on the first page of a website (Price, name, currency, change etc)

```
Public Sub GetTeamData()
Dim strWebAddress As String
Dim strH2AnchorContent As String
Dim IEDocument As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim objH2 As MSHTML.HTMLHeaderElement
Dim obTable As MSHTML.HTMLTable
Dim objRow As MSHTML.HTMLTableRow
Dim objCell As MSHTML.HTMLTableCell
Dim lngRow As Long
Dim lngColumn As Long

' initialize some variables that should probably better be passed as paramaters or defined as constants
strWebAddress = "https://toolkit.financialexpress.net/santanderam"

dateNow = Now
bExitLoop = False
lngTimeoutInSeconds = 5
Do While Not bExitLoop
  If Now > DateAdd("s", lngTimeoutInSeconds, dateNow) Then Exit Do
Loop

' open page
Set IEDocument = GetIEDocument(strWebAddress)
If IEDocument Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Timeout reached opening this address:" & vbNewLine & strWebAddress, vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If

    Dim ButtonData As Variant
    Set ButtonData = IEDocument.getElementsByClassName("paginator fe-paging-navContainer")

Dim button As MSHTML.HTMLLinkElement
For Each button In ButtonData

   Debug.Print button.nodeName

        button.Click

          ' retrieve anchor element
          Set oTable = IEDocument.getElementById("Price_1_1")
             Debug.Print oTable.innerText

              ' iterate over the table and output its contents
              lngRow = 1
              For Each objRow In oTable.Rows
              lngColumn = 1
              For Each objCell In objRow.Cells
                  Cells(lngRow, lngColumn) = objCell.innerText
                  lngColumn = lngColumn + 1
              Next objCell
              lngRow = lngRow + 1
           Next
         Next button
End Sub
```

My problem is that I cannot get the data to pull through from the next pages (1..7).

Can anyone please help with why the above wont pull data through from the next pages? 
Thank you!

Comment: Do they have known URLs for the additional pages?  You can always run your subroutine for each URL, provided they are not dynamically named.

Comment: they all have the same URL unfortunately :(

Comment: My other suggestion would be to check for the DOM (HTML) expressions for each of the tabs from page 1 through 7.  There would have to be some delimiter in the DOM explorer (via IE) to have them be on different pages.  You would just need to fully inspect the element for those delimiters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the bit of code that opens the page, replace the rest of the code with the below code. You might have to tweak it a bit but it should go through all available pages:

```
' Set the object for 'Next' button
Dim oNext As Variant
Set oNext = IEDocument.getElementsByClassName("ui-paging-button ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-paging-next")

' Loop to go through all pages
Dim bExitMLoop As Boolean: bExitMLoop = False
lngRow = 1
Do While Not bExitMLoop

    ' Get data from current page
    Set oTable = IEDocument.getElementById("Price_1_1")
    For Each objRow In oTable.Rows
        lngColumn = 1
        For Each objCell In objRow.Cells
            Cells(lngRow, lngColumn) = objCell.innerText
            lngColumn = lngColumn + 1
        Next objCell
        lngRow = lngRow + 1
    Next

    ' Check if Next button is available
    If oNext.Length = 0 Then
        bExitMLoop = True
    Else
        oNext.Item(0).Click

        ' Wait for page to refresh (could check the ready state here as well)
        dateNow = Now
        bExitLoop = False
        lngTimeoutInSeconds = 3
        Do While Not bExitLoop
            If Now > DateAdd("s", lngTimeoutInSeconds, dateNow) Then Exit Do
        Loop

        ' Reset 'Next' button object
        Set oNext = Nothing
        Set oNext = IEDocument.getElementsByClassName("ui-paging-button ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-paging-next")
    End If

Loop
```

Comment: thank you!! I get an object required error when I run this - im probably missing something really obvious but cant see why this would be?

Comment: I think I've spotted it. In your code, your table is being set within the `FOR` loop so when you removed the code, table is no longer set. Set your table within the `Do` loop before the `FOR` loop

Comment: After the line `For Each objRow In oTable.Rows`

Comment: Read my comment above yours. You are missing the table object. Ive updated my code above

Comment: Ah thanks! I know im being a complete pain but I'm getting an error "Application-defined or object-defined error" in the `Cells(lngRow, lngColumn) = objCell.innerText
            lngColumn = lngColumn + 1` Ive never seen this error before any ideas?? Also I really appreciate all your help!!!

Comment: :) no worries. That's because `lngRow` has no value when you come in the loop. Have `lngRow = 1` Just before the `DO` loop. That should resolve the problem

Comment: :( SORRY one last question (honest!) It wont pull through the last page, as (I'm assuming the o.Next>0 isn't valid on this page?), can I add an exception line so it will pull through the final page?

Comment: So its not pulling the data from last page?

Comment: I've update the answer to cater for last page. I'm not a big fan of adding exceptions in code unless necessary. I've added a flag in the loop which detects if Next button is available or not. This way it will still pick up data from last page before exiting the loop